# is there any msi keyword or special role in php query for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I was looking at someone else's PHP, MySQL code and that code is as below:

```
$sql='select max(sample_id) msi from sample where sample_id>\''.$first_sample_id.'\' and sample_id<\''.$last_most_sample_id.'\'';
```

Now when i look at the SAMPLE table in mysql db. it has no any colum named msi. so i am confused why msi is used? does it has any special meaning?

Comment: `msi` is a field __alias__.

Comment: As a side note, this is not a very good practice for how to request data from PHP, as this method is prone to "SQL injection" attack. Please take a look at `mysqli` or `PDO` functions, and `prepared statements` as the good way to make queries. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Msi is the alias of the column selected. Same as the following:

```
select max(sample_id) AS msi
```

Otherwise the column returned would have **max(sample_id)** as its name.

You can learn more about this here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp